# Java - Retrieve second element xml-document - DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom

How do I retrieve the color-element and its attributes in the following xml-doc

```
 <drawingobject>
    <oval x="240" y="325" width="15" height="15" filled="yes">
        <color r="0" g="255" b="255"></color>
    </oval>
</drawingobject>
```

and the dtd look likes this for the oval

```
 <!-- elementet oval -->
<!ELEMENT oval (color?)>
<!ATTLIST oval x CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST oval y CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST oval width CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST oval height CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST oval filled (yes | no) "no">
```

I can retrieve the element "oval" and its attributes, but do not know how to test if it contains a color-element and IF - retrieve it.

Here is the code

```
 private void parse() throws Exception {

    String docName = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/" + "myxml.xml";
    File file = new File(docName);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = db.parse(file); 
    NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("oval");
    oval = new int[nodeList.getLength()][5];

    for(int i= 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

        oval[i][0] = Integer.parseInt(nodeList.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("x").getNodeValue());
        oval[i][1] = Integer.parseInt(nodeList.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("y").getNodeValue());
        oval[i][2] = Integer.parseInt(nodeList.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("width").getNodeValue());
        oval[i][3] = Integer.parseInt(nodeList.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("height").getNodeValue());

        if (nodeList.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("filled").getNodeValue().equals("yes")) {
            oval[i][4] = 1;
        } else {
            oval[i][4] = 0;
        }


       Element ovalNode = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
       NodeList colorNodes = ovalNode.getElementsByTagName("color");
       if(colorNodes.getLength() > 0) {
            System.out.println(colorNodes.item(i).getNodeName()); 
       }

    }
```

Stacktrace

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at test.parse(test.java:60)
at test.<init>(test.java:28)
at test.main(test.java:17)
```

the *System.out.println(colorNodes.item(i).getNodeName());*  is at row 60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you're doing to get the `oval` elements: by using `Element.getElementsByTagName(String elementName)`. You already have the `oval` elements that you're looping over, so you can just call this method on each iterated element:

```
for(int i= 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
   ...

   Element ovalNode = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
   NodeList colorNodes = ovalNode.getElementsByTagName("color");
   if(colorNodes.getLength() > 0) {
        System.out.println(colorNodes.item(0).getNodeName());  // prints "color"
        ... // do something with the node
   }
}
```

Comment: ok, but I get a NullPointerException at the line "System.out ..." when trying this code. What could the reason be?

Comment: @java Could you update with the new code and the exception stack trace?

Comment: @java I had a typo in my snippet: `colorNodes.item(0)` instead of `colorNodes.item(i)`. I meant to get the first `color` node. If there can be more than one `color` nodes, then you can loop over them similar to what you already do with `oval` nodes.